# Django Python | Returning Render(request) and HTTP Reponse at the same time?

Tags: python, django, http, httpresponse

I'm trying to return a Render(request) and an HTTPReponse at the same time..

```
def home(request):
    db_userpull = user.objects.all().values_list('userkey', flat=True)
    
    http_resp = HttpResponse()
    http_resp.set_cookie('foo', 'bar')




    #return render(request, 'home.html', {"db":db_userpull})

    #return http_resp

    return render(request, 'home.html', {"db":db_userpull, "sesstest":request.session['user_s_key']}) , http_resp
```

Essentially the goal is, on load the page displays stuff from the database, and create a Cookie using an http response at the same time..

When I return them separately, they work fine (either creates a cookie, or returns the database data)

I'm trying to get it to return both, but I'm getting an Attribute Error;

```
AttributeError at /
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: the django render method will take the `request` as an arg, so you may be able to add the cookie to the request or the session.

Comment: please refer django's cookie and session https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/